# How to assign value from dictionary (which is a list) to new List?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a populated dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, List <KeyValuePair<string,string>>> actions 
   = new Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>();

if (!actions.ContainsKey(srcID))
{
    actions.Add(srcID, new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>());
}
actions[srcID].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(dstID, command));
```

Now I would like to create a new list and assign to it values (which is also a list) from above dicionary.
Something like this: (what would be the correct syntax?)

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> actions = dic[srcID, command]
```

Comment: `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list = actions[srcID];` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply assign the list in the constructor of the list if you wish to create a new list. If not just use the `dic[srcID]` value

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> actions = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
(dic[srcID]);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you just need to specify your **key**

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> actions = dic[srcID];
```

That will return you a Value that corresponding to that Key which is a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.Also you might want to use implicit type definition with `var` keyword which makes your work easier in this case.Because you have a long variable name:

```
var actions = dic[srcID];
```